# Comparing two lists of different length and returning data

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with two worksheets `F1` and `F2`. 
On each, `Column A` is last names, `Column B` is first names, and `Column C` is department names. `F2` lacks the department names.

I am trying to compare and match the names in `F2` with the names in `F1` and return the department names from `F1`'s `Column C` to `F2`'s `Column C`.

The difficulty I'm having is that `F1`'s list is significantly longer than `F2`'s list. Otherwise I could just do a simple comparing thing.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Would there ever be a case where the same First and Last name points to two different departments?

Comment: Do you need just find department Manfred, our also "compare"? What compare means for you. Can you add a helper column to F1? If yes then you can easily solve your problem with `VLOOKUP`

Comment: No. There shouldn't be at least.

Comment: I just need to return the department names from F1 to F2. I can add a helper column. What would I need to do at that point?

Answer (score 1):

So if we have data like this:

#### Sheet F1

```
     A           B          C
----------------------------------
Last Name   First Name  Department
Bar         Foo                  1
Bar2        Foo                  2
Bar3        Foo                  3
Bar4        Foo                  4
```

And we want this:

#### Sheet F2

```
     A           B          C
----------------------------------
Last Name   First Name  Department
Bar3        Foo                  3
```

You can use an array formula in column C (entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>)

```
=INDEX(F1!C:C,MATCH(CONCATENATE(F2!A2,F2!B2),CONCATENATE(F1!A:A,F1!B:B),0))
```

Then fill down to suit

If you find the execution time to be too long for that formula you can narrow down the `CONCATENATE` range to your specific data.  i.e.:

```
=INDEX(F1!C:C,MATCH(CONCATENATE(F2!A2,F2!B2),CONCATENATE(F1!$A$1:$A$5,F1!$B$1:$B$5),0))
```

Comment: So fast.  I was busy taking screenshots...  I always use `&` to join simple strings, but we're doing the same thing.

Comment: Excellent. This worked very well, thank you so much. For some it didn't return the departments but that is because F2 is user-submitted while F1 is our database - so any misspellings wouldn't match. But your formula got about 180 of the 210 all sorted. I can handle doing 30 manually. :-)

Comment: @bentosmith Ah well if you perhaps play around with using wildcards "*" within the concatenate those 30 "might" match.  But you also might get some false positives...  Glad it worked though